# ALM for Powerapps

Tags: azure, devops, powerapps, alm

I want to know that after exporting solution to azure devops repos can we edit the code or add new features to the solution from repo itself by adding few lines of code and also i am able to see only files in XML format.
Actually in power app while editing we have some visualization of things but how can you do it in repos while developing new features. Please suggest if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the exported files is currently not supported. You must edit from within the designers in the browser. For powerapps (canvas apps) specifically, there is currently not an offline editing story, but if it does become enabled in the future, you'll see it on the blog at: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog

There are ALM tools for importing, exporting , and working with Azure DevOps. See https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-general-availability-of-microsoft-power-platform-build-tools/

Update: We've just announced new tooling to support this:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Language-Tooling

More here: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/source-code-files-for-canvas-apps/